# How to make the button auto-clicked on page load in Xamarin?

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin

How can I make my button auto clicked as the page loads into my application, then calls the event that it supposed to execute? Here's my code in my xaml file for button.

```
<Button Text="Click Me!" x:Name="scanButton" HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" />
```

Comment: Why not separate a code into a function and call it from the both event handlers?

Comment: Like, how am I going to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Make a method of the task you want to perform on button click and call that method when the page appears, you should use the `Lifecycle` events to perform this, see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29252552/6105461) answer for the events