# Check if ContentPage is currently shown

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

Is there a way to tell if a ContentPage is currently shown?

I need code inside an event handler in the ContentPage to check whether the page is currently shown and act accordingly.

Comment: Register event handlers OnAppearing and remove on Disappearing then you don't have to worry about it. If you are using event handlers for IPC you are going to have a bad time and might want to refactor things a bit.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In addition to GBreen12's answer, you could also do it this way...

```
bool isShowingMyPage = Application.Current.MainPage is MyPage || (Application.Current.MainPage is NavigationPage navPage && navPage.CurrentPage is MyPage); //If you are using a MasterDetailPage or something else, then you would have to handle this differently

//I think the below will work for checking if any modals are showing over your page but you should definitely test it in different scenarios to make sure. I am not sure if the modal is immediately removed from ModalStack when it gets popped or not

isShowingMyPage = Application.Current.MainPage?.Navigation?.ModalStack?.LastOrDefault() == null;
```

Comment: What if this page has been "pushed" or "pushed modal" over the `MainPage`?

Comment: @ispiro If a new page was "pushed" over `MyPage` then `Application.Current.MainPage` would hold the new page and not `MyPage`. If you also need to worry about whether a modal is showing over your `MyPage`, then check out my edit.

Comment: Checking for modals worked

Answer (score 2):

You can override `OnAppearing` which is called anytime the page is about to be shown:

[Page lifecycle events in xamarin.forms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29252351/page-lifecycle-events-in-xamarin-forms)

Comment: Thanks. I thought of that, and keeping a bool flag. But I wonder if there's any built in way.

Comment: problem is on droid it fires before the page displays and on ios its after the page is displayed..

Answer (score 1):

You can listen to the `NavigationPage`'s `Pushed` and `Popped` events, like so:

```
((Xamarin.Forms.NavigationPage)MyProject.App.Current.MainPage).Pushed += (s, e) => 
{
    if (e.Page is ContentPage)
    {
        // Do what you gotta do
    }

    // or, for a specific page:
    if (e.Page is MyProject.Views.MyCustomPage)
    {
        // Do what you gotta do
    }
};
```

Of course, this will only be called when the page is pushed onto the navigation stack; If you need it to be called each time the page appears on the screen, then go with what GBreen12 or hvaughan3 said.

Comment: I found this thread when I had the same problem. However, this solution does not work for me:
1.) Because I used the tempates generated by Visual Studio, `MainPage = new AppShell();` and not the page I am interested in.
2.) This page can be called as FlyoutItem as well as over `GoToAsync`. So `OnAppearing` is called when the page has been constructed (but hidden by `CurrentItem`), but is not called when this page appears after the overlay page is destroyed.