# Check if ContentPage is currently shown: Solution not working for me

Tags: events, xamarin.forms, onappear

I used the same title as [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48629640/check-if-contentpage-is-currently-shown) because the solutions offered there are not really useful for me:

1.) Because I used the templates generated by Visual Studio, `MainPage = new AppShell();`, `Application.Current.MainPage` is always `AppShell`.

2.) This page is defined as FlyoutItem but is also called over `GoToAsync`. So `OnAppearing` is called when the `FlyoutItem` has been initalized (but hidden by another page defined in `CurrentItem`), but will not be called when this page appears after selecting by the FlyoutMenu.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Shell what you will have to do is get the current displayed Shell page.

```
var currentPage = Shell.Current.CurrentPage;
```